# ERROR: ORA-1033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I got stuck with a problem.
I have started my Oracle SQL*Plus today and I got this error :

> ORA-1033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress.

I am using Oracle 11g enterprise edition.
I have also tried these steps in command window :

```
sqlplus /nolog

SQL> connect / as sysdba
```

but still it's showing same error.

Please someone help me to solve the problem.

Comment: So what happens when you try connecting as SYSDBA? Does that work? If so try running `select status, database_status from v$instance;`

Comment: it is showing ora-01031:insufficient privileges

Comment: i have tried select status, database_status from v$instance; it is showing sp2-0460:not connected

Answer (score 0):

It may be the case the database did not stop correctly.
Try out following.
Open Dos command Prompt

```
c:>sqlplus/nolog
sql>connect sys/manage as sysdba
sql>shutdown immediate enter code here 
sql>startupsql>exit
```

While startup it may ow error message like some of the parameter is missing. Note down that parameter and update in initS.orafile.
RUSHIL

Comment: Any particular reason for not adding spaces between words in a sentence? It is really hard for people to understand what you are saying there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the help. I guess Reinstalling the oracle was the only solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The given below is the process to resolve ORA-011033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress:

To resolve the error go to command prompt (cmd)
c:\sqlplus /nolog

SQL> connect / as sysdba

Connected.

SQL> shutdown abort

ORACLE Instance shut down.

SQL> startup nomount

ORACLE Instance started

SQL> alter database mount;

SQL> alter database open;
Still, if the given below error occurs

ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kcratr1_lostwrt]

Then do the following:

SQL> startup mount

ORACLE Instance started

SQL> recover database

Media recovery complete

SQL> alter database open;

Database altered